# When to use 'one' instead of indefinite article 'a'?

Tags: word-usage, articles

I'm confused about using the word *one* or *a* at times.

> I was walking down the street and saw **one** person climbing the building. 
>   I was walking down the street and saw **a** person climbing the building.

Which one is correct? Why?

Comment: Likewise, *There was no **one single person** doing work during the office hours.* Cannot it be said *There was no single person/no person doing work during the office hours.* Is it all about emphasizing your statement by simply putting one and single altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you use "a". You would use "one" in cases where you need to emphasize the number of people, which might happen if there were different numbers of people doing things.

> I was walking down the street and saw a person climbing the building.

The emphasis is on who is doing what.

> I was walking down the street and saw one person climbing the building, two people watching, and another person calling the police.

The number of people doing each thing is also emphasized.

Comment: How can *one* tell if this answer is right?

Comment: This explanation is quite general. Indeed, I'd use the *number* if I am concerned about the *number of people* but my friend, *"I was walking down the street and saw one person climbing the building."* is **the end of the story!**

Comment: The explanation is general because you offered no context. I assumed that these were examples you had written yourself. If you would like to identify the story and perhaps include a whole paragraph, I'll look again. It would have also been useful to know that you were talking about a (fiction?) story rather than typical conversational usage.</br>@Happy, it's true that *one* is used to refer to a generic person when used as a noun, but not when used as an adjective.